# Pipeline bash commands echo and bc into a C program

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2, execl

I'm trying to do a little C program that realize a pipeline of two bash commands : echo $arithmeticOperation | bc

$arithmeticOperation is a string taken as input.

The program works fine executing first command, but when i run the second one, i get the right output but the child process executing bc remains stuck preventing the child from ending.

So in this line father process is blocked :
               waitpid(pid2,NULL,0);

Where do you think the problem may be ?

Sorry if i asked the question incorrectly, it's my first one. Thanks.

```
    #define SYSCALL(r,c,e) if((r=c)==-1) { perror(e);exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    int main(){
        char buf[128];
        int pfd[2],err;
        pid_t pid1,pid2;
        SYSCALL(err,pipe(pfd),"pipe");
        switch (pid1=fork()) {
            case -1: { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
            case 0 : { 
                scanf("%s",buf);
                SYSCALL(err,dup2(pfd[1],1),"dup");
                close(pfd[1]);
                close(pfd[0]);
                execl("/bin/echo","echo",buf,(char *)NULL);
                return 1;
            }   
        }   
        switch (pid2=fork() ){
             case -1 : { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
             case 0 : { 
                 SYSCALL(err,dup2(pfd[0],0),"dup");
                 close(pfd[1]);
                 close(pfd[0]);
     //          execl("/usr/bin/bc","bc",(char *)NULL);
                 execlp("bc","bc",(char *)NULL);
                return 1;
            }   
        }   
    printf("waiting . . . \n");
    waitpid(pid1,NULL,0);
    printf("wait\n");
    waitpid(pid2,NULL,0);
    close(pfd[1]);
    close(pfd[0]);
    return 0;
    }
```

So if i digit "1+1" as a input string i get the right output but then the process executing bc never exit

Comment: Your parent process must close the pipe file descriptors before waiting so `bc` gets EOF.

Comment: It's solved thanks so much.

i should call   close(pfd[ ]);   before wait instead after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187565/pipeline-bash-commands-echo-and-bc-into-a-c-program#comment99000900_56187565), your parent process must close the file descriptors for the pipe *before* waiting for `bc` (and you've agreed that this fixes the problem).

This arises because `bc` has the pipe open for reading, and the parent has the pipe open for writing, and the kernel thinks that the parent could therefore send data to `bc`.  It won't, but it could.

You have to be very careful when managing pipes.  You carefully avoided the usual problem of not closing enough file descriptors in the children.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

---

I need to extend that to cover parent processes too.

If the parent process is not going to communicate with any of its children via the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe so that its children can receive EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on write), rather than blocking indefinitely.  The parent should normally close at least one end of the pipe — it would be extremely unusual for a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.